# Генерация случайного текста как на bash.im

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Меня заинтересовал способ, которым на башорге формируют цитату для вставки на сайт. 
FAQ [тут](http://bash.im/webmaster/)
Посмотрев, что нужно обращаться к js скрипту на bash.im/forweb, то я сразу же перешел на эту страницу и начал рассматривать её на наличие скриптов, которые и берут случайную цитату из базы. И что самое странное - я их не нашел. 
Можете ли описать такой способ?
А если такое не получится с MySQL, то можете объяснить, как с помощью js из базы выводить определенный текст на стороннюю страницу?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так js здесь по сути не при чем. 
При обращении по адресу http://bash.im/forweb/?u (для UTF-8 например) просто возвращается javascript который собственно и выполняется. Javascript не работает с БД. С БД работает PHP. Ну как с помощью PHP вытащить случайную цитату из БД я думаю объяснять не стоит. Ведь так?

Comment: @kryDos , про php конечно же не надо. 
Получается мы на странице /forweb  тупо формируем js? и потом через 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bash.im/forweb/"...

его просто выполняем?

Comment: Да примерно так.

Comment: @KryDos , спасибо. А то я уж тут себе напридумывал кучу сложностей.

Comment: @KryDos , столкнулся с проблемой. файл forweb.php не может исполнять JS . Получается придется воспользоваться AJAX запросами к php скрипту, чтобы получить случайный текст и вывести его через файл forweb.js?

Comment: я не очень понял вопрос :( Файл forweb.php и не может выполнять js. javascript выполняется на машине пользователя а не в каком-то файле. 
Вам нужно с помощью, например, file_get_contents() обратиться по адресу http://bash.im/forweb/?u и возвращенный результат отдать пользователю.